# some jar files run via double click, and some don't

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, jar, swt

I started to use SWT (eclipse.org/swt). Exporting my project to a run-able jar only runs through a command line, i.e. `java -jar filename.jar`. However does not work when I double click it. But in the same time, I can double click on other jars, and they run perfectly fine!
What can be wrong with this jar?

Comment: On which OS (Windows, Linux, macOS)?

Comment: On a Windows 10 computer.

Answer (score 0):

How does java know which class to run, since a .jar file contains many .class files?

The answer is you need a manifest file named META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. Put it into the root of your .jar file, and add a line like this:

```
    Main-Class: com.something.MyApp
```

You just need the one line. There are other things you can put in, such as the app version, any special classpath if one is required, etc. Check your .jar file and see if this file is present -- if not, you have to create it.

You can also use Eclipse Wizards to help you create a MANIFEST.MF file. Simply right click on your project, choose Export | Jar File, and follow the wizard pages. Use 'Next' instead of 'Finish', because the option to select a Main Class is on one of the non-required pages.

You stated that your MANIFEST.MF has lines like

```
    Rsrc-Main-Class: Main
    Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

This means that when you execute the .jar. it looks for a main() method in the Eclipse supplied class JarRsrcLoader. That class is probably in your path when you run the .jar while Eclipse is running. But I don't think it will work if you stop Eclipse.

Comment: now it generates me something like:
`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Sealed: true
Main-Class: my.p.Main`

It works via java -jar , but again not by double click...

When I double-click it says _could not find main class: my.p.Main_

**my.p** is just the package of the Main

Comment: Look inside the .jar file you created (Use "jar tvf <jarfile>"). Is your class present at /my/p/Main.class? And are there additional .jar files inside the .jar you created?

Comment: there is Main.class inside /my/p/
I don't see other jars, but there are some swt dlls, and SWT class files

Answer (score 0):

The java which is used from the command line and the java, which is used by double clicking may be 2 different versions of java. Check which version is used from the command line: java -version.

For the java used when double click, use the Windows SDK tool - File Type Verifier.

Once you have it, you should be able to reproduce the error from the command line. You may have more output then.

Comment: From the command line there is no problem reported. I associated the runnable jar first with jre 8 and later with openJava jdk 14 an both do NOT start the jar with a double click. I also checked the registry and added the jar option, but that did not help either.

Comment: Where you able to verify the jar file using the File Type Verifier?

Answer (score 0):

Do not bother with the runnable jar in Windows but use launch4j to make an .exe and run that. If you encounter problems run the .exe by clicking the play button in launch4j, because launch4j gives you a console to display error messages.